# Javascript mouse tracking speed

Tags: javascript, tablet-pc, stylus-pen

I was working on a tablet PC using zoho notebook (http://notebook.zoho.com) earlier today and noticed that stylus input is not as accurate or smooth as something like say, OneNote. It seems like the functionality is done in javascript, so my question then becomes: Is it possible to increase the accuracy (for pen tool functionality that is similar to zoho notebook) that javascript tracks the mouse/stylus such that writing with the stylus flows more naturally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are hardware bound. The problem lies with the capturing device, not the software used.